# SFTP backup directories from source RHEL server to target RHEL server

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a shell script which copies backup directory from my source server and put them into a diffrent directory on target server by sftp command.
Additionaly after putting the file into target server, I want to compare the size of source and target server to verify the sftp was completely successful or not.

Comment: Why do you want to use `sftp`? There are easier tools that also run over `ssh`

Answer (score 0):

Use a specified tool instead of `sftp` to do this, e.g. `rsync`:

From source server:

```
rsync -av -e ssh /path/to/files target-server:/path/to/backup/
```

From target server:

```
rsync -av -e ssh source-server:/path/to/files /path/to/backup/
```

This has the benefit that it will copy only files changed or even only the changes within a file. It's doing a comparison of size and modification time by default, but you can use `-c, --checksum` to compare based on checksum.

Add `--delete` to remove files that have been deleted on the source server.